# ASIHTTPRequest async request in model class

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I want to use ASIHTTPRequest or ASIFormDataRequest in my model class.
How can I delegate or detect request status, and return value.

Such as:

I've a Controller having IBAction DoIt:sender. I want to call Connector->DoIt and call my Controller back when connection successfull or fail.

How can I handle it?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read this? http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use Also don't use ASIHTTP, its been pretty much dead for a good few years. AFNetworking is THE networking library now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback based (from [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)):

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

   // Use when fetching binary data
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

Block based:

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setCompletionBlock:^{
      // Use when fetching text data
      NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

      // Use when fetching binary data
      NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
   }];
   [request setFailedBlock:^{
      NSError *error = [request error];
   }];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}
```